# robot gets stuck in front of obstacle while using navigation stack

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with navigation robot in obstacle situation, using navigation stack.

For the test, I put the robot, obstacle, target in the same line and see if it can avoid the obstacle and go to target, making a curve path.

As I anticipate, the navigation global path is made in a curve to avoid the obstacle. However, the local path does not follow the global path and make the robot get bumped to the obstacle while taking much time to escaping from it.

Is there any way to make the local path be aware of the global path?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410933/robot-gets-stuck-in-front-of-obstacle-while-using-navigation-stack/) by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-12-28**:
What do you mean when you say that the robot does not follow the path? Is it not moving at all, or is it moving incorrectly?

**Comment by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on 2022-12-28**:
@ljaniec Yes It moves incorrectly! And I figured out that the path I uploaded is global path while the local path keeps ignoring the obstacle. So I change the topic from 'robot does not follow path in collision' to 'local path ignores obstacle'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@mirakim It would be helpful to see your YAML file with local planner configuration.

You can read more about parameters here: https://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=melodic

If you are using TEB planner, check this: https://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner

If DW, the first link has a section about it.

The obstacles should be visible in the costmap, perhaps this piece of info is missing and is a source of error?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0